# Docker swarm and ipv6 on node

Tags: docker, ipv6, docker-swarm

I have docker cluster.

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  manager:
    image: busybox
    networks:
      - frontend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  worker:
    image: busybox
    depends_on:
      - manager
    networks:
      - frontend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.label.name == hp-laptop]

networks:
  frontend:
```

On host with label **hp-laptop** i have ipv6 address.

```
ping6
PING google.com(lhr.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from lhr.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=36.6 ms
64 bytes from lhr.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from lhr.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=30.6 ms
```

How i can provide ipv6 support from **host (hp-laptop)** to **docker swarm node** using docker stack configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPv6 doesn't work in Overlay networks](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24379#issuecomment-357480199). You'd have to use bridge networks.